# Elements.getTypeElement() returns TypeElement with empty annotations

Tags: annotation-processing

I'm working on annotation processor and in general it works as expected. I've successfully extracted annotated elements by calling `RoundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith()`. Then I extracts annotation mirrors by calling `Element.getAnnotationMirrors()` to process annotation parameters. I work with annotation mirrors instead of annotation directly to provide graceful error handling with the help of the messager.

The problem appears when I try to do the same, but with the element obtained via `Elements` util class. If I extract exactly the same element by calling `Elements.getTypeElement()` and then call `Element.getAnnotationMirrors()` it returns an empty array. It seems like element's metadata is not initialized at all. Note, that it happens ***only*** for types that are ***not*** part of the round environment (i.e. are not processing right now)

I haven't found any evidences in javadocs is it intended by design or not. Maybe it is just a bug. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? Could be be (for example) related to the RetentionPolicy of the annotation in question?